# List of supported graphics cards for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, ati, graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit on an Intel i7-3700 system, and I've just found out the hard way that my intel HD 4000 integrated graphics is not supported on the OS. Because of this, my dual monitor setup doesn't work, nor am I getting native resolution on my monitors.

I don't need fancy 3D graphics, just need it to work and get native resolution on my 2 monitors and support an extended desktop on my dual monitor setup (1 connected to VGA, the other to DVI).

I'm thinking of getting a cheap graphics card to circumvent this problem. Is there a list of graphics cards/chips by ATI/nvidia/etc that are well supported on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit out of the box?

Thanks.

Comment: when you are using latest hardware why not use latest OS. Use 12.04LTS. It does support these cards.

Comment: I have a specific need to use 10.04 as I'm using a specific tool chain that doesn't support newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

nvidia drivers support Ubuntu on most of its cards. What I would do is find a card you like, make sure its a nvidia, and search the nvidia site for ubuntu drivers for it. Then if you want to be really safe google for errors with ubuntu and that card.

Comment: This isn't right always. nvidia optimus enabled laptop hardly support multi monitor setup. Though the drivers are the listed in nvidia.

Comment: So what are some supported cards? Mine's a desktop btw.